# C# How to change ID3v1 tag taglib

Tags: c#, taglib

When im trying to change id3v1/2 tags:

```
string path = @"C:\test_song.mp3"

        TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(path);
        f.Tag.Album = "232424_v2";

        f.Save();
```

I have a problem with id3v1. It was not changed.
How i can edit both versions? 
Or how i can edit only id3v1?
Please, help! Thanks!

Comment: The ID3 version 1 is really simple and is completely different from version 2. You have to check if your library suppors ID3v2.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string path = @"C:\test_song.mp3";

TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(path);
Tag tagv1 = f.GetTag(TagTypes.Id3v1);
tagv1.Album = "232424_v2";
Tag tagv2 = f.GetTag(TagTypes.Id3v2);
tagv2.Album = "232424_v2";

f.Save();
```

Comment: Thank you.
But it is not working(
I see(through AIMP3) that v1 is not changed.

Comment: I checked the v2 but not the v1. I'm sure the v2 one is definitely working, not sure why v1 is not working

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem with images.
with debug, i understood that when "TagTypes" is null is not working.
i don t know why, usaually in my cases appened when images are bigger then 1mb.

[image]